# VBA Range.Formula issue

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im confused with the range.formula on excel VBA,
Im trying to use the formula `RIGHT`as follows on my VBA code:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LR
    cel = "A" & i
    cel2 = "P" & i
    cel3 = "Q" & i
    Range("R" & i).Formula = "=RIGHT("cel", "cel2" & "" - "" & "cel3")"
```

The last row of my code, I trying to do `right(A1, P1-Q1)`
However, Im getting syntax error and Im struggling to solve

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use & when concatenating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very, very close:

```
Sub marine()
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LR
        cel = "A" & i
        cel2 = "P" & i
        cel3 = "Q" & i
        Range("R" & i).Formula = "=RIGHT(" & cel & "," & cel2 & " - " & cel3 & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]